# How to keep list view scrolling position in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my todo app I have two Bottom Navigationbaritem of todo list and todo completed list..

I want to move back to that position of list view where I reached last time,

in short I want to keep scrolling position so that I can scroll from that position not from beginning while coming back to that navigation bar item..

here is my code

and let me know what topic should I learn for it...

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int selectedindex=0;
  final tabs=[
    TodoList(),
    TodoCompletedList(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Todo App'),),
        body:tabs[selectedindex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
          currentIndex: selectedindex,
          onTap: (index){
            selectedindex=index;
            setState(() {
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.fact_check_outlined),
                label: 'Todos'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Completed',
                icon: Icon(Icons.done))
          ],
        ),


    );
  }

}

class TodoList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 40,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(),
            title: Text('Item No.'+(index+1).toString()),
          );
        });
  }
}


class TodoCompletedList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(),
            title: Text('Item No.'+(index+1).toString()),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` might be another option

Answer (score 1):

I got my Answer from the stack overflow old question and answer

Just adding key page storage and done

Page Storage Key : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html

```
ListView.builder(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>('todolist'),
        itemCount: 40,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(),
            title: Text('Item No.'+(index+1).toString()),
          );
        });
```

Comment: Or you can use IndexStack widget Like, body : IndexedStack(index: selectedindex, children: tabs)